# how do I return form inputs and update javascript variables in running total calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a calculator, which calculates the total from a sum of pre-defined inputs. Users are allowed to change the inputs anytime and the total should update automatically.

So far I've manage to create calculator which takes the pre-defined input variables and displays the total, but I'm struggling to get the total to update when the user inputs a new variable into the form.

I've tried a couple of different things to return the inputs from the form and replace the global input variables ("input1" and "input2") but they haven't worked. Any help would be very much appreciated, Mike.

```
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<br>TOTAL: <div id="chkTotal"></div>
<br>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1"/>
<input type="button" value="Change input 1" onclick="GetTotal(this)"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2"/>
<input type="button" value="Change input 2" onclick="GetTotal(this)"/>

<script>
  var input1 = 11692;
  var input2 = 13

$(document).ready(function() {
  GetTotal();
  SetInputVariables();
});

function GetTotal(txtBox) {
  var total = 0;
  document.getElementById("input1").value = input1;
  document.getElementById("input2").value = input2;
  $('input:text').each(function(index, value) {
    total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
  });

  $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's always easier for others, if you provide [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're constantly overwriting the input box values with your predefined ones. Run the prepopulation code only once:

```js
var input1 = 11692;
var input2 = 13;

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("input1").value = input1;
  document.getElementById("input2").value = input2;
  GetTotal();  
});

function GetTotal() {
    var total = 0;

    $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
      total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    });

    $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}

GetTotal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
TOTAL:
<div id="chkTotal"></div>
<br>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" onkeyup="GetTotal()" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" onkeyup="GetTotal()" />
```

*Note: added onkeyup listener to the inputs instead of those external buttons for each input*

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for